# Firefox 89 on Pi - visual codec artifacts

Tags: video, ubuntu, firefox

Firefox 89 on my Pi 4 is displaying bad codec symptoms, videos can be watched but the picture is corrupted by brightly coloured patches around areas of detail.

On the Pi I am running Ubuntu 21.04 and I am very pleased with it.

My preferred browser is Firefox which has been working well until the upgrade to version 89. By way of a check, I did the same Firefox 89 upgrade on a PC which is also running Ubuntu. On the PC Firefox still works perfectly.

Am I alone in this or have others seen the same issue ?

Assuming I am not alone, does anybody have any idea what has gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer to my question. For all the detail see here:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1338832

Which boils down to:
in
about:config
set
gfx.webrender.force-disabled = true

Comment: When the timer expireres, don't forget to mark your answer as the asnwer :)